# Line-Height - Não Deixa Texto Verticalmente Centralizado

Tags: html, css, font

Estou usando o `line-height` para centralizar um texto verticalmente. Mas o texto me parece que está com uma pequena margem. Vejam na imagem abaixo, selecionei a fonte para verem melhor o espaçamento que está fazendo a diferença na hora de centralizar.

Tem como corrigir isso ?

[image: Imagem]

```
#userNome{
    width: 98%;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    line-height: 2;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-family: "Luckiest Guy";
    color: #AF3846;
    font-size: 26px;
    &.show{
        display: block;
    }
}

<div id="userNome">Olá, Diego Souza</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O `line-height` não serve para alinhar o texto na vertical, quem faz isso é o `vertical-align` (no seu caso, você quer `vertical-align: middle;`).

No entanto, o `line-height` é necessário pelo fato de o `vertical-align` alinhar de acordo com a altura da linha e não do container em que está o texto, ou seja, você continua precisando do `line-height`.

Comment: Já usei o `vertical-align` com `display:table` e `display:table-cell`, mas não funcionou. Ficou da mesma maneira. Acho que a fonte é assim...

Comment: @Oeslei não é necessário especificar unidade de medida para line-height.

Comment: @natan Você está certo. Corrigi a resposta!